# Qt threading, ensuring order of message queue / dequeue and understanding thread space

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I'm practicing with Qt (5.5) threads. In the example below the order in which messages are queued / dequeued is of importance. My idea is to create a ProducerThread intance, initalised to a member of a different class. Through this member calls will be made to `ProducerThread::enqueRecord` in order to enqueue messages to the ProducerThread's member queue which is of Qt's type `QQueue`.

I have the following two questions:

(1) I'm thinking about ensuring the order in which messages are queued / dequeued by making use of a `QReadWriteLock`. Is this the recommended approach?

(2) I'm not sure if the calls to enqueueRecord are executed on the main application's thread or on the ProducerThread. As explained above, I was thinking of creating an initializing a class member with an instance of ProducerThread, and then I will call make calls to the enqueueRecord method through that member.

```
ProducerThread::ProducerThread(QObject *parent):
    _parent(parent)
    _running(false);
{
    //..
}

ProducerThread::~ProducerThread()
{
    //..
}

void ProducerThread::enqueueRecord(QString record)
{
    queue.enqueue();
    if (!_running) {
        start();
    }
}

ProducerThread::run()
{
    _running = true;
    while (!recordQueue.isEmpty()) {
        qDebug() << recordQueue.dequeue(); // TODO
        QThread::msleep(1000);
    }
    _running = false;
}
```

Comment: Why are you checking if queue is empty by polling? The standard way to have a queue like that is to use condition variable, in Qt's case http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwaitcondition.html

Comment: About read-write lock, what do you think is "reading" in your use case? Note that taking an item from queue is "writing" (queue is modified).

Comment: About Qt threading, even if you override `QThread` (which I think is reasonable if you want to have your own queue), I would advice putting all code which is intended to run in the thread in it's own separate classes, so that only thing in the `QThread` subcalss which runs in the thread is the `run()` method. This is because `QThread` object itself does not live in the thread it controls, and it can get difficult to separate code and variables which are meant to run in a specific thread, or which are supposed to be thread safe.

Comment: About `enqueueRecord`, if your `run()` method does not call it directly or indirectly, then it is not called in that thread. It doesn't get magically called by itself!

Comment: @hyde, Thx for your comments, this make it a bit more clear. Regarding reading / writing; With reading I refer to getting items from the queue, with writing putting items on the queue.

Comment: QThread is more like a thread controller. Unless you want to change how threading works in Qt, you'd be better off not inheriting from QThread. A great example of how to use this class is described [here](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/).